# Convert tSQL statement string into final value

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a column of type *`NVARCHAR` which holds SQL statement snippets instead of the final values. So for example one of the fields holds the following snippet:

```
CAST(@originalValue * -1 AS INT)
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to use these SQL snippets to be inserted into stored procedure code latter on. To validate the functionality I have created the following very simple example to set an integer value to (5) and use the above SQL snippet within dynamic SQL statement to invert this value (5) into (-5).

```
DECLARE @originalValue AS INT = 5
DECLARE @fianalValue AS INT
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @value AS NVARCHAR(50) = 'CAST(@originalValue * -1 AS INT)'

SET @sql = 'SELECT @fianalValue = '+CAST(@value AS NVARCHAR(100))+''

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@fianalValue INT OUTPUT', @fianalValue = @fianalValue OUTPUT

PRINT '@fianalValue: ' + CAST(@fianalValue AS VARCHAR(50))
```

However, I am getting an error. I have tried in a few different approaches but something is not lining up. Thank for help.

Comment: What's the error? You have a suspicious star in your `@value` value.

Comment: the error is: Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the scalar variable "@originalValue" and the suspicious star is mathematical operator - Multiplication :)

Comment: Doh! Wonder how I could have misread that as an error :) You need a parameter list defined. I forget how to do that, though. Google for an example.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. What "parameter list" ? There is only one single value. Please explain. Thx.

Comment: In order to define `@originalValue` within the dynamic statement, I mean. Else, how would SQL know what you mean by that?

Comment: yes, that was the original idea. When I provide the value into the string snippet as: DECLARE @value AS NVARCHAR(50) = 'CAST(5 * -1 AS INT)' that will obviously work but that misses the point since the numeric (5) is a variable value

Comment: `@originalValue`is not declared in the same scope you run your query in. You need to define it either in the string, or "add" it to the string as you do `@value`

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

DECLARE @originalValue AS INT = 5
    DECLARE @fianalValue AS INT
    DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @value AS NVARCHAR(50) = 'CAST('+convert(varchar(20),@originalValue)+' * -1 AS INT)'


    SET @sql = 'SELECT @fianalValue = '+CAST(@value AS NVARCHAR(100))+''

    exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@fianalValue INT OUTPUT', @fianalValue = @fianalValue OUTPUT

    PRINT '@fianalValue: ' + CAST(@fianalValue AS VARCHAR(50))
```

Comment: ...well, I am not sure how this is going to behave under some large dataset updates but this works. Thx!

Comment: ...sorry that I did not get to this earlier. The problem with your solution is that the @value declaration resolves at the time of the declaration itself so it will never make it into the dynamic SQL as a "string". Instead it will be supplied as previously resolved value which is missing the point. Thx.